# shell case arguments go to the default one

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm coding a shell script with options. I don't understand why my script go to the default option directly.

here the script ;

```
args=("$@")
ELEMENTS=${#args[@]}

LENGTH=$#


if [ $LENGTH -eq 0 ] || [ $LENGTH -ne 10 ]
then
    args[0]="-h"
    ELEMENTS=1
fi

for ((i=0; i<$ELEMENTS; i++ ))
do

    PARAMETER=${args[${i}]}

    case $PARAMETER in

    -H)
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
        HOSTNAME="${args[${i}]}"
        ;;

    -C)
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
        COMMUNITY="${args[${i}]}"
        ;;

    -T)

        i=$(( i + 1 ))
        TYPE="${args[${i}]}"
        ;;

    -i)
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
        INTERFACE="${args[${i}]}"
        ;;

    -h|--help|*)
            echo "Usage:

./check_CMT.sh -H <HOSTNAME> [-C <COMMUNITY>] -T <TYPE> -i <INTERFACE>

            TYPE:

            1. INTER -- gr-0/0/0
            2. SPEED
            3. ERROR
            4. DISCARD
            5. STATUS
            6. TRAFIC

-h |  --help --> For help"

            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
```

When i execute the script i have directly the last echo.

```
./check_interface.sh -H ip_address -C Comm -T SPEED -i gr-0/0/0
```

I think that i used the correct options. Please let me know if you found the error in my code. Thanks

Comment: BTW, don't use all-caps names for your own variables. See POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: "The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities." -- keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: Why use `args` at all? Ultimately, you can simply use `for parameter in "$@"; do case $parameter of ...`.

Comment: I changed to upercase letters and the solution of chepner. It's working. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started your script with 8 parameters. As that's not 0 nor 10, `args[0]` is set to `-h` and `$ELEMENTS` to 1.

You can use `set -xv` to debug your scripts (that's what I did).